# Trouble with discrete MeshRegions: Integrating over plane slices

Tags: graphics3d, regions, mesh, finite-element-method, rendering

I would like to slice a *discrete* 3D region with a plane, and integrate some field over the resulting 2D region (embedded in 3D). Let me be clear: I do not mean analytical regions (the kind you could define via ImplicitRegion), but specifically discrete regions, as in my project I am importing those from experimental data.

There are two strategies I have tried. Here is a quick summary:

- **Strategy 1** is to use `SliceContourPlot3D` with `RegionFunction` to obtain a 2D region (i.e. surface) embedded in 3D. The problem is that the mesh is faulty and has no boundary, so I cannot e.g. compute fluxes through it. Any suggestions fixing this are more than welcome.
- **Strategy 2** is to transform the problem to in-plane coordinates (i.e. make it a genuine 2D problem) and use the standard two-dimensional `RegionPlot`. *This works*. The drawback is that the mesh is purely 2D (no longer embedded in 3D), so I cannot superimpose the result with the original geometry, which is important to me. If there is a nice way of translating/rotating `DG2` (effectively increasing its `RegionEmbeddingDimension` from 2 to 3) I would be very grateful to know.

Now I will construct a simple discrete region and expand the strategies 1 & 2:

```
IR = ImplicitRegion[
   x^6 - 5 x^4 y + 3 x^4 y^2 + 10 x^2 y^3 + 3 x^2 y^4 - y^5 + y^6 + 
     z^2 <= 1, {x, y, z}];
MR = DiscretizeRegion[IR];
```

Now I would like to slice MR with some plane.

**Strategy 1: `SliceContourPlot3D` with `RegionFunction`**

Ideally the outcome would be a MeshRegion with `RegionDimension` 2 and `RegionEmbeddingDimension` 3. According to [this discussion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48486/high-quality-regionplot3d-for-logical-combinations-of-predicates), because `RegionPlot3D` performs badly with logical statements, a good way to do it is via `ContourPlot3D` combined with `RegionFunction`. Here is my attempt:

```
reg = 1.5;
RP = SliceContourPlot3D[
   1, {x, y, z}.{-1, -1, 1} == 0, {x, -reg, reg}, {y, -reg, 
    reg}, {z, -reg, reg}, PlotPoints -> 20, 
   RegionFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y, z}, SignedRegionDistance[MR, {x, y, z}] < 0]];
DG = DiscretizeGraphics[RP];
DG // FindMeshDefects
RegionBoundary[DG]
```

[image]

Unfortunately there are mesh defects and probably as a result of that, the `RegionBoundary` is not computed correctly - it should be a 1D curve. This becomes a big problem when I try to integrate some field over it:

```
Integrate[Exp[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], {x, y, z} \[Element] DG]
```

[image]

In summary, I have sliced a 3D mesh successfully, obtained a 2D slice embedded in 3D. However, the problem with the boundary prevents me from analysing the slice (e.g. computing fluxes through it). Any suggestions for fixing this are very welcome.

**Strategy 2: A plain two dimensional `RegionPlot`**

Here is an alternative approach to the problem, which does work but is less convenient. The idea is to find the in-plane coordinates (not shown here) and treat a 2D region using the classic RegionPlot:

```
reg = 1.5;
RP2 = RegionPlot[
   RegionMember[MR, {x, y, 0}] == True, {x, -reg, reg}, {y, -reg, 
    reg}, PlotPoints -> 10];
DG2 = DiscretizeGraphics[RP2];
FindMeshDefects[DG2]
DG2 // RegionBoundary
```

[image]

There are no mesh defects, and the boundary is computed correctly. Integrating some field over `DG2` or its boundary is now no problem (thanks to Henrik Schumacher for helping with this in the comments):

```
Integrate[Exp[x^2 + y^2], {x, y} \[Element] DG2]
Integrate[Exp[x^2 + y^2], {x, y} \[Element] RegionBoundary[DG2]]
```

The drawback is that the mesh is purely 2D (no longer embedded in 3D), so I cannot superimpose the result with the original geometry, which is important to me. If there is a nice way of translating/rotating `DG2` (effectively increasing its `RegionEmbeddingDimension` from 2 to 3) I would be very grateful to know.

**Comment/Disclaimer**

I have a feeling Mathematica is not designed for what I am trying to do, but this is not completely obvious to me from documentation. `MeshRegions` Which come from `ImplicitRegion` or predefined regions like `Ball[]` appear to be discretized very differently from inherently discrete regions. The current question is an extension of [my previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155484/is-it-possible-to-re-mesh-downsample-upsample-a-discretizeregion-object).

Comment: Sorry, I cannot reproduce `RP2`. (I have only MMA 11.0.1; maybe that is the reason.) Note however that DG2 is a 2-dimensional MeshRegion and thus has infinite `ArcLength` (read `ArcLength`  as 1-dimensional Hausdorff measure). `ArcLength[RegionBoundary[DG2]]` will give you the desired result.

Comment: Thank you, that's a very helpful comment about the arclength. As expected `NIntegrate[1, x \[Element] RegionBoundary[DG2]] - 
 ArcLength[RegionBoundary[DG2]]` is close to zero. However, any idea why `NIntegrate[x, x \[Element] RegionBoundary[DG2]]` returns two values rather than one? P.S. Which part were you unable to reproduce? Does `DiscretizeGraphics` fail by any chance? I'm on MMA 11.0.1 too.

Comment: In this integral, `x` is a point, hence `NIntegrate[x, x \[Element] RegionBoundary[DG2]]` should return the barycenter of the boundary curve times arclength of the boundary curve.

Comment: And forget about my comment about RP2. After restarting the kernel it works (although I was pretty sure that I had restarted it already).

Comment: Sorry, but can you explain a bit more about why NIntegrate provides the barycenter*arclength? Naively I would have expected an integral of x over a curve, which should be a scalar. I seem to be missing something.

Comment: Here, `x` is not a parameterization parameter of the boundary curve; its a (2-dimensional) point on the curve. Maybe, it becomes clearer if you consider expressions of the form `NIntegrate[f[x], x \[Element] RegionBoundary[DG2]]`, where $f \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is a function on the plane. Then `NIntegrate` tries to approximate $\int_{\partial \operatorname{DG}} f(x) \, \operatorname{d} \mathcal{H}^1(x) \in \mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: I see, so my mistake was to specify `x \[Element] RegionBoundary[DG2]]` instead of `{x,y} \[Element] RegionBoundary[DG2]]`. With the latter I get a scalar (as expected) integrating a function over a curve  `Integrate[Exp[x^2 + y^2], {x, y} \[Element] RegionBoundary[DG2]] (* Out: 25.8366 *)`.

Comment: Yepp, you got it!

Comment: Thank you Henrik. This helped me make the question more precise and I wrote an update. Perhaps my best course of action is to go with the 2D `RegionPlot` solution. However, as described in my updated question, I would really like to translate and rotate the 2D `MeshRegion` in 3D space, increasing its `RegionEmbeddingDimension` from 2 to 3. If you know of a way to do that I would be very grateful to learn.

Comment: You can reembed the DG2 back to $\mathbb{R}^3$, e.g., with `MeshRegion[
 Transpose[
  Append[Transpose[MeshCoordinates[DG2]], 
   ConstantArray[0., MeshCellCount[DG2, 0]]]],
 MeshCells[DG2, 2]
 ]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your surface to intersect with is given by an implicit equation (such as $z=0$ in your example), `SliceContourPlot3D` can produce quite acceptable results.

```
IR = ImplicitRegion[
   x^6 - 5 x^4 y + 3 x^4 y^2 + 10 x^2 y^3 + 3 x^2 y^4 - y^5 + y^6 + 
     z^2 <= 1, {x, y, z}];
MR = DiscretizeRegion[IR];
f = {x, y, z} \[Function] z;
plot = SliceContourPlot3D[1, f[x, y, z] == 0, {x, y, z} \[Element] MR];
DG3 = DiscretizeGraphics[plot];

Show[
 MeshRegion[RegionBoundary[MR], PlotTheme -> "Lines"],
 DG3,
 Axes -> True,
 Boxed -> True
 ]
```

[image]

Unfortunately, `RegionBoundary[DG3]` will not produce any `MeshRegion` that represents the boundary curve any more...

This must be done by hand. Fortunately, `SliceContourPlot3D` creates line objects for the boundary curves, deeply hidden within a `GraphicsComplex`. We just have to parse it and reorder some vertex positions:

```
BDG3 = Module[{gc, lines, plist, pts, s},
  gc = Extract[plot, Position[plot, _GraphicsComplex]][[1]];
  lines = Extract[gc, Position[gc, _Line]][[All, 1]];
  plist = Union @@ lines;
  pts = gc[[1, plist]];
  s = AssociationThread[plist -> Range[Length[plist]]];
  MeshRegion[
   gc[[1, plist]], (x \[Function] Line[Lookup[s, x]]) /@ lines]
  ];
Show[
 MeshRegion[RegionBoundary[MR], PlotTheme -> "Lines"],
 DG3,
 BDG3,
 Axes -> True,
 Boxed -> True
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution is absolutely brilliant, especially the second part where you extract the boundary points. Would there be a way to construct a `MeshRegion` from `BDG3`, so that I could integrate some field over? Ideally I would have a `MRPerfect` such that `Integrate[Exp[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], {x, y, z} \[Element] MRPerfect]` works, and such that `BDG3` would be the `BoundaryMesh` of `MRPerfect`.

Comment: I tried `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[BDG3]` which fails. Perhaps Mathematica does not recognise that all points are in a plane. I suspect that one would have to pick a point in the region (say `RegionCentroid`) and then manually define triangles from there to every boundary point.

Comment: @AlexanderErlich `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` works only for (n-1)-dimensional MeshRegions embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $n\in \{2,3\}$. "Boundary" in Mathematica tends to mean "topological boundary" rather than "boundary of a manifold".  Thus, in its current implementation, you cannot achieve `BDG3 == BoundaryMesh[MRPerfect] ` being true. This is why I defined `BDG3` by hand. Use `DG3` above as the "interior".

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to Henrik's brilliant and very low level solution, I would like to propose an alternative based on my "Strategy 2". The idea is to transform the problem to 2D, solve it in 2D, then re-embed in 3D.

First, I find a set of appropriate in-plane basis vectors `bvec1`, `bvec2`:

```
IR = ImplicitRegion[
   x^6 - 5 x^4 y + 3 x^4 y^2 + 10 x^2 y^3 + 3 x^2 y^4 - y^5 + y^6 + 
     z^2 <= 1, {x, y, z}];
MR = DiscretizeRegion[IR];

x0vec = {1/2, 1/3, -1/3};
normal = {1, - 1, 1} // Normalize;
bvec1 = Cross[{0, 0, 1}, normal] // Normalize;
bvec2 = Cross[normal, bvec1] // Normalize;
```

Next, we use the 2D variant of RegionPlot to extract the region and its boundary:

```
DG2D = DiscretizeGraphics[
   RegionPlot[
    RegionMember[MR, x0vec + a*bvec1 + b*bvec2] == True, {a, -2, 
     2}, {b, -2, 2}]];
DG2DBoundary = RegionBoundary[DG2D];
{DG2D, DG2DBoundary}
```

[image]

As ultimately my goal is to integrate over these regions, I refine the mesh via `ToElementMesh`:

```
(* optional: enhance 2D region *)
<< NDSolve`FEM`
DG2D = MeshRegion[
   ToElementMesh[DG2DBoundary, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.005]];
{DG2D, DG2DBoundary}
```

[image]

Now we can embed the regions in 3D by directly manipulating coordinates:

```
EmbedMeshRegionIn3D[reg_] := Module[{coords},
  coords = {x0vec + #1 bvec1 + #2 bvec2 } & @@@ MeshCoordinates[reg];
  MeshRegion[Flatten[coords, 1], MeshCells[reg, RegionDimension[reg]]]
  ]
DG3D = EmbedMeshRegionIn3D[DG2D];
DG3DBoundary = EmbedMeshRegionIn3D[DG2DBoundary];
MeshRegion[EmbedMeshRegionIn3D[#], Boxed -> True] & /@ {DG3D, 
  DG3DBoundary}
```

[image]

Not sure what the weird colouring on the left image is about (`DG3D // FindMeshDefects` finds no problems).

We now plot the results, with the in-plane basis vectors `bvec1`, `bvec2` in blue and surface normal in red:

```
Show[
 MeshRegion[RegionBoundary[MR], PlotTheme -> "Lines"],
 MeshRegion[DG3D, MeshCellStyle -> Green],
 MeshRegion[DG3DBoundary, 
  MeshCellStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[0.015]]],
 Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[x0vec, 0.1]}],
 Graphics3D[{Red, Arrow[Tube[{x0vec, x0vec + normal}, 0.02]]}],
 Graphics3D[{Blue, Arrow[Tube[{x0vec, x0vec + bvec1}, 0.02]], 
   Arrow[Tube[{x0vec, x0vec + bvec2}, 0.02]] }],
 Axes -> True, Boxed -> True]
```

[image]

Now, let us integrate over the 2D and 3D region and see if the results are the same. First, a test to make sure that areas are is computed correctly:

```
    NIntegrate[1, {x, y, z} \[Element] DG3D] == 
     NIntegrate[1, {a, b} \[Element] DG2D] == Area[DG3D] == Area[DG2D]
(* OUT: True *)
```

Note that if you omit the mesh refinement step (the part with `ToElementMesh`), this will return `False`, and the area computation is somehow messed up:

```
NIntegrate[1, {x, y, z} \[Element] DG3D] - Area[DG3D] 
(* OUT: -0.254965 [if mesh refinement is omitted] *)
```

Finally, we can integrate some field over the region. Let us compare the integration in 2D and 3D as a test:

```
field[x_, y_, z_] := Exp[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]
flux2D = NIntegrate[
   field @@ (x0vec + a*bvec1 + b*bvec2), {a, b} \[Element] DG2D];
flux3D = NIntegrate[field[x, y, z], {x, y, z} \[Element] DG3D];
flux2D == flux3D
```

After a long day:

```
(* Out: True *)
```

Answer (score 3):

The `MeshFunctions` option of `RegionPlot3D[]` can also be used to generate an initial slice for further refinement:

```
(* mesh to be sliced *)
IR = ImplicitRegion[x^6 - 5 x^4 y + 3 x^4 y^2 + 10 x^2 y^3 + 3 x^2 y^4
                    - y^5 + y^6 + z^2 <= 1, {x, y, z}];
MR = DiscretizeRegion[IR];

(* plane parameters *)
x0vec = {1/2, 1/3, -1/3};
normal = {1, -1, 1} // Normalize;

p1 = RegionPlot3D[MR, Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshFunctions -> {normal.({#1, #2, #3} - x0vec) &},
                  PlotPoints -> 155];

slice = DiscretizeRegion[Polygon[First[Cases[Normal[p1], Line[l_] :> l, ∞]]], 
                         MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 0.05}]
```

[image: slice of a mesh]

Let me stress again that this is only a starting point; the resolution of the contour produced by `MeshFunctions` is not that high, and thus needs to be further refined (e.g. with the methods in Alexander's answer).