# Can I trust area calculations over discrete MeshRegions? Flipped triangles, possible visual bug

Tags: plotting, regions, finite-element-method, mesh, rendering

The following code produces a `MeshRegion` in two different ways. Unfortunately, the first method produces weird artifacts in `RegionPlot` and `Plot3D`, whereas the second method causes no such problems. I am hoping to find out if this purely a visual bug or if the mesh is actually corrupted in the first example.

On Mathematica 11.0.1.0 Windows x64 I get the following output:

```
(* first method *)
<< NDSolve`FEM`
EM1 = ToElementMesh[Circle[], MaxCellMeasure -> Infinity];
MR1 = MeshRegion[EM1];

(* second method *)
MR2 = DiscretizeRegion[Disk[]];

RegionPlot /@ {MR1, MR2}
Plot3D[-Exp[x^2 + y^2], {x, y} \[Element] #] & /@ {MR1, MR2}
```

[image]

I suspect that this is purely a visual bug because the area of `MR1` is calculated very precisely: `Area[MR1]/Pi` returns `0.996981`. Also, `FindMeshDefects@MR1` returns no defect. I would hope that someone could shed a light on this weird (visual?) bug, as I am working with discrete `MeshRegions` like the one from the first method and I am not fully sure if I can trust the area calculations any more.

**EDIT**: The use of `RegionPlot` applied to `Regions` is advertised as a new feature in Mathematica 11 [here](https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/visualization--labels-scales-exclusions/plot-over-regions.html). The conversion between MeshRegion and ElementMesh is discussed in Section "Comparing ElementMesh and MeshRegion" of [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html) tutorial.

**EDIT2**: I think the documentation of `MeshRegion` and/or `ToElementMesh` need to make the differences between inbuilt regions and discretized regions abundantly clear. [This](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html) tutorial is a good start but the main documentation is lagging behind. There are many undocumented subtleties that you can only learn from other users. For instance:

- As we see in the present question, `RegionPlot` struggles with `MeshRegions` of `MeshOrder` 2, but does OK with an `ElementMesh` of the same order: `RegionPlot /@ {EM1, MeshRegion[EM1]}`. I believe the use of `RegionPlot@EM1` is undocumented, so is `MeshOrderAlteration`, I learned it from user21's answer to the present question.
- Boolean operations such as `RegionDifference` work for inbuilt regions
  like `Disk[]`, but not for discretized regions. I know this because
  C.E. told me so in his answer to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155484/is-it-possible-to-re-mesh-downsample-upsample-a-discretizeregion-object) question.  think it's not
  obvious from the documentation that inbuilt and discretized regions
  are not treated on the same footing. To achieve boolean operations
  of discretized regions, you need workarounds such as the one
  demonstrated by Henrik Schumacher in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/156295/trouble-with-discrete-meshregions-integrating-over-plane-slices) question.

I hope these problems can be addressed in future versions and the documentation can be updated.

Bug reported to Wolfram CASE:3983893.

Comment: When discussing a potential bug, always give sufficient informations for others to reproduce it, including the version of Mathematica you are using. I see no problem with M11.2 / OS X.

Comment: Use ElementMesh as the input of MeshRegion and use MeshRegion as input of RegionPlot are not documented.. So not sure we can call these as bug.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you, added!
@halmir `RegionPlot[True, {x, y} \[Element] MR1]` has the same problematic output.

Comment: @Szabolcs on V11.2.0/OSX I get the same thing as the OP.  `EM1` works fine (if I replace `MR1` by it).  `MR1` displays correctly, too, but the `RegionPlot` of it has the problems in the question.

Comment: MR1 built by the undocumented input. and RegionPlot[True, {x, y} \[Element] MR1] is not documented ...

Comment: @halmir I find it a bit disingenuous to say that "it's not documentation in this precise form so it's not a bug" when it is very clear that something is broken.  Also, you are simply wrong that it is not documented. It is used multiple times in the various FEM tutorial pages.

Comment: @MichaelE2 You are right, I made a mistake.

Comment: It is documented. See Section "Comparing ElementMesh and MeshRegion" in http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html

Comment: I didn't know it's documented in tutorial, since I didn't see any usage in MeshRegion documentation.  It's a bit surprising.  Even MeshCells on MR1 return internal function form..

Comment: @Szabolcs What I mean is if something is broken by undocumented usage, then it's more like a suggestion than a bug.

Comment: Also, plotting over regions is advertised as a new feature in Mathematica 11: https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/visualization--labels-scales-exclusions/plot-over-regions.html

Comment: Using regions is now documented for `Plot3D`; it wasn't in V10 even though the functionality was clearly intended. Currently `RegionPlot[reg,...]` is still not documented, although examples appear in doc pages other than the documentation page for `RegionPlot`. Some options have no effect, and one does not have a good idea of the extent and limitations of what can be done. When all else fails, I use the documented `DiscretizeRegion` instead of `RegionPlot`. -- That said, the behavior above is clearly unacceptable, and anything so irritating to customers ought to be called a bug.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the correct way to do it:

```
RegionPlot /@ {EM1, MR2}
Plot3D[-Exp[x^2 + y^2], {x, y} \[Element] #] & /@ {EM1, MR2}
```

[image]
[image]

What you are seeing has to do with the fact that `ElementMesh` use higher order elements  (`EM1["MeshOrder"]`) to approximate the region and functions that take `MeshRegion` as an argument can not handle that.

To check the area of the `ElementMesh` use

```
\[Pi] - Total[EM1["MeshElementMeasure"], 2]
0.009482917945401237`
```

But here is a much more subtle thing to be aware of. If you use the full dimensional region i.e. `Disk` (like you did in your `DiscretizeRegion` example - why the inconsistency?) not `Circle` you get a much better representation:

```
EM2 = ToElementMesh[Disk[], MaxCellMeasure -> Infinity];
\[Pi] - Total[EM2["MeshElementMeasure"], 2]
2.2342021526178257`*^-6
```

It may be possible to improve the `Circle` case but it's not a high priority.

Another thing you can do is convert the higher order `ElementMesh` to a first order mesh and then do the conversion like so:

```
RegionPlot[MeshRegion[MeshOrderAlteration[EM2, 1]]]
```

**Comments**

A few things to know: An `ElementMesh` is not a Region as you can check that with `RegionQ`. This may change in the future but that's the situation in V11.2. The primary purpose in `ElementMesh` 's life is to serve as a mesh for the Finite Element Method and have a default mesh order of of 2. As such the `ElementMesh` is used in `NDSolve` and related functions such as InterpolatingFunction objects. It can also be used in NIntegrate. I think all of these usages are shown in one of the FEM tutorials. An `ElementMesh` can be converted to a `MeshRegion` and the resulting `MeshRegion` is also second order accurate. This is undocumented `MeshRegion` functionality but needed to make the geometry frame work to work. A conversion to a second order `MeshRegions` does not mean, however, that all functions (that allow `RegionQ`) can deal with that (yet), which is understandable, I think. But does that mean an `ElementMesh` should also be first order accurate only? Certainly not - that would give lousy FEM results. So what you see here is issues/bugs as the arise at the interface of projects. I filed the plotting over second order mesh regions as a bug; that said I can not say when it's fixed as this is not my department and I have little control over that. The documentation you cite as 'a good start' is one from the FEM framework that I wrote. If you have suggestions for that I am open to changes etc; but I am not going to document short comings of MeshRegion there - it's just not the right place. So my suggestion is that you report `MeshRegion` issues to wolfram. It does make a difference if issues are reported in house or by customers. Having said that I added an example for `MeshOrderAlteration` to the `ElementMesh` generation tutorial, pending approval. The fact that you can plot over `ElementMesh` is made use of several times in that tutorial - granted it does not show it for every single plot... So, again, if you have anything that is `ElementMesh` oriented and you'd like to see documented or where the documentation should be improved let me know.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the kind of answer I was hoping for. The fact that `RegionPlot` is made for `MeshOrder` 1 explains everything. A few remarks: 1) `Plot3D[-Exp[x^2 + y^2], {x, y} \[Element] EM1]` returns error message on my machine: `Plot3D::idomdim: {x,y}\[Element]EM1 does not have a valid dimension as a plotting domain.`. 2) Yet another undocumented feature (AFAIK) is that you can integrate over an `ElementMesh`: For instance, `NIntegrate[
    Exp[x^2 + y^2], {x, y} \[Element] #] & /@ {MeshOrderAlteration[
    EM1, 1], EM1 } // Differences` works.

Comment: Just as a personal note, this is now my third question related to discrete MeshRegions (the other two are [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/156295/trouble-with-discrete-meshregions-integrating-over-plane-slices) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155484/is-it-possible-to-re-mesh-downsample-upsample-a-discretizeregion-object)). Pre-programmed regions like `Disk[]` and discrete ones (coming from `ToElementMesh` or imported from STL) are really not on the same footing in MMA. I think the documentation of e.g. `MeshRegion` should highlight that more.

Comment: @AlexanderErlich if you have suggestions for how the FEM documentation or functionality should improve (e.g. `ToElementMesh`), I am all ears and I'll try to make it happen. For other things (like `MeshRegion`, `DiscretizeRegion`) it's probably better to contact support and send in your suggestions.

Comment: @AlexanderErlich, the `Plot3D` error is fixed in V11.2.

Comment: Thank you, I wrote some suggestions/thoughts as EDIT2 in the main question.

Comment: Does that help? Let me know if I can help more, I'm already using discrete regions for a project and frequently getting frustrated with things like undocumented functionality. I'd be happy to keep adding to that list of suggestions if that has any prospect of helping/being heard.

Comment: @AlexanderErlich, I need to attend to something else first, but I will comment on this. Please be patient. I may take a few days before I get to it.

Comment: @AlexanderErlich added a few thoughts. Let me know what you think.

Comment: I finally got around to submitting a few bug reports, this one is CASE:3983893. The bug is the weird plots seen above which come up when you try to use `RegionPlot` or `Plot3D` with a `MeshRegion` which has higher `MeshOrder` than one. Thank you for all your help here @user21.