# How to reduce the number of triangles in a mesh?

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, mesh

I am trying to turn a `Graphics3D` object (the Stanford Bunny) into a mesh. The result from using `DiscretizeGraphics` has too many triangles.

Is there a way to reduce the number of triangles in a mesh while maintaining its form?

I have attached a picture of the bunny for reference.

[image: Too-triangular bunny]

Comment: Welcome to the site, mikabozu! The research field related to your question is called *mesh simplification*, which is a quite dedicated topic. A lot of resources, like papers and open courses, can be found online.

Comment: Have you seen [Is it possible to re-mesh, downsample & upsample a DiscretizeRegion object?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/155484/731)?

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi:  Ummm... why did you post the exact same link as C.E. nine hours later??

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Whoa! I certainly did not do that. What I did do was vote to close as Duplicate and picked that link as the duplicate. Does that action automatically add a comment?

Comment: @C.E. I have seen that question, but the solution provided there does not seem to work on the bunny. It continues to have the same number of faces. Also, I am not sure if one could use such a method to, say, reduce the number of triangles by 90% or more.

Comment: As I understand it, the topic is hard from a discrete differential geometry view point. One of the difficulties is to maintain or gracefully simplify the topology of the region. But nowadays, people are trying to view it as a 3D image processing problem, so some CNN based methods are proposed, e.g. [this one from Siggraph 2019](https://ranahanocka.github.io/MeshCNN/). If you are just looking for a quick tool, I'd suggest looking in the machine learning direction.